# Finding min and max from data file

Tags: c, input, max, min

I am trying to write a simple program that reads integers from a data file and outputs the minimum and maximum value. The first integer of the input file will indicate how many more integers will be read, and then the integers will be listed.

Example input file:

5 100 -25 42235 7 -1

As simple as this is, i'm not sure where to start. I imagine I will need to create an array of size = the first integer, then increment my position in the array and compare to a min/max value.

I am not sure what the syntax would be to declare an array with the first integer, then fill the array with the remaining integers, or if that is even the right approach. After creating the array, I should have no problem assigning values to min/max variables with a loop increasing position through the array.

Comment: Is each number on a separate line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use an array to store data.  You just need to find out minimum and maximum values from data received from a file.

```
long lMin = 0, lMax = 0;
int nCount;
long lNo;
// open file
fscanf( file, "%d", &nCount );
for( int i = 0; i < nCount; i++ )
{
   fscanf( file, "%ld", &lNo );
   if( lNo > lMax )
       lMax = lNo;
   if( lNo < lMin )
       lMin = lNo;
}
printf(" Min = %ld Max = %ld\n", lMin, lMax );
// close file
```

Comment: This doesn't work if all the values are > 0 (it will mistakenly say that the min is 0) or if all the values are < 0 (it will mistakenly say that the max is 0).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an array. Just keep track of the current minimum and maximum (they start as the first number you read). After you read each number, if it's lower than the minimum it becomes the new minimum, and if it's higher than the maximum it becomes the maximum.

Comment: I guess i'm just confused about the format of the input file. The first integer of the input file indicates how many MORE integers are in the input file, but is not actually a member of the set of numbers I am trying to find min/max of.

Comment: Read the first number and save it as the count. Then after you read each number, decrement the count -- when you reach 0, you're done.

Comment: Or loop up to the count. e.g., off the top of my head (may be buggy), `int readnumber() {/* write this */} int main(void) { int min = INT_MAX; int max = INT_MIN; int count = readnumber(); for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){ int n = readnumber(); if (min > n) min = n; if (max < n) max = n;} printf("min = %d max = %d\n", min, max); return 0; }`

Comment: @JimBalter Please don't try to put long code excerpts in comments, they're unreadable because there's no formatting. Post an answer.